# How do I Start Multiple Bounties for one single question

Tags: support, bounty

How do I start multiple bounties? I just started one and there's no obvious way to start another one.

Comment: Do you want to assign more than one bounty to a single question, or one each to different questions?

Comment: @Jake I'd like to have multiple bounties for one single question.

Answer (score 12):

You can't assign more than one bounty to a question at a time. From the [Bounty Help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> Questions may only have one active question bounty at any given time.

Note that you *can* have more than one active bounty, but these have to be assigned to different questions:

> Users may only have three active bounties at any given time.

Comment: I missed that one. I suppose this means you have to award the bounty before you can start another one. Shame. I can only award the current one after 22 hours.

Comment: I just awarded a bounty and started a new one. The instructions for adding a bounty clearly state that you can have up to _three simultaneous bounties._ It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: "Simultaneous" here means "simultaneous in time", not "simultaneous in space (i.e. question)". You (as a single user) can have three different bounties for three different questions at the same time, but a question can't have three bounties at the same time (whether by the same person or by three different people).

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Why didn't you accept this answer? Aren't you satisfied with it?